# Should one generally develop a client library for REST services to help prevent API breakages?

Tags: rest

We have a project where UI code will be developed by the same team but in a different language (Python/Django) from the services layer (REST/Java). The code for each layer exits in different code repositories and which can follow different release cycles. I'm trying to come up with a process that will prevent/reduce breaking changes in the services layer from the perspective of the UI layer.

I've thought to write integration tests at the UI layer level that we'll run whenever we build the UI or the services layer (we're using Jenkins as our CI tool to build the code which is in two Git repos) and if there are failures then something in the services layer broke and the commit is not accepted.

Would it also be a good idea (is it a best practice?) to have the developer of the services layer create and maintain a client library for the REST service that exists in the UI layer that they will update whenever there is a breaking change in their Service API? Conceivably, we would then have the advantage of a statically-typed API that the UI code builds against. If the client library API changes, then the UI code won't compile (so we'll know sooner that there was a breaking change). I'd also still run the integration tests upon building the UI or services layer to further validate that the integration between UI and the service(s) still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a client layer is a very good idea, not only to manage the interface but as a convenience to the developer of the client who may not have the skills to correctly build the client layer.  I disagree that the person to build the client layer is necessarily the  developer of the RESTful server API.  You should find a developer with the appropriate skills and assign the task to him/her.

The idea about successful testing as a condition of commit is an excellent one, although if you're using maven you can be a little more selective about when in the overall process those test are performed.

My only suggestion above what you've proposed is that you consider a lightweight, template-based code generator for the task of building server, client and testing layers.  EMFT JET in the M2T Eclipse project is a very good solution.  You might like other code generation technologies.